# Is it possible to "rorate" columns

Tags: css, html-table, rotatetransform

In the table below header texts have been easily rotated using CSS.
Then in order to see the full texts I can either rotate the columns, which does not seem possible, or enlarge them, what I do not want to do.
I can also add texts on top of the table, out of the header, but this will be a mess to adjust their positions and impossible in responsive design.

Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a web search?  Is this what you want to achieve? https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/

Comment: Or maybe this here?  https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers-now-with-fewer-magic-numbers/